# How to filter json data based on key value pair using jq?

Tags: select, key-value, jq

Suppose I have some json data given below:

```
{"name":"alon","department":"abc","id":"ss12sd"}
{"name":"kate","department":"xyz","id":"ajsj3" }
{"name":"sam","department":"abc","id":"xx1d2"}
```

I want to filter data based on particular department and save it in a different json file. From above data suppose I want to filter all the data whose department is 'abc' and save it in some new json file. How I can do this using jq. I am checking it's manual from [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters) but didn't understood that much.

Answer (score 3):

```
jq 'map(select(.department == "abc")) ' yourfile.json
```

Comment: How I will let jq knows what is my input json file and where I should specify output filename

Answer (score 2):

A flexible template might be like this:

```
jq --arg key department --arg value abc \
'.[] | select(.[$key] == $value)' input_file.json > output_file.json
```

This way you can change the criteria at the arguments stage rather than the expression.

Implementing that into a shell script might look like this:

---

**myscript.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
key="$1"
value="$2"
file="$3"
outfile="$4"
jq --arg key "$1" --arg value "$2" \
'.[] | select(.[$key] == $value)' "$3" > "$4"
```

Which you would invoke like so:

```
./myscript.sh department abc input.json output.json
```

---

Edit: Changed `."\($key)"` to `.[$key]` - thanks @peak

Comment: Yeah, that work. Actually my input file looks like below:

    {"name":"alon","department":"abc","id":"ss12sd"}
    {"name":"kate","department":"xyz","id":"ajsj3" }
    {"name":"sam","department":"abc","id":"xx1d2"}

Then if I am trying to run above query it's throwing error

    jq: error (at test.json:1): Cannot index string with string "location"

Comment: Cannot index string with string "department"